# GNOME smart hide launcher doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome

I am using Ubuntu and decided that I wanted to use GNOME instead of Unity, so I installed it and removed Unity.

But now I am having a big problem. The launcher/dock is hidden at all times, except when I tap the Windows-button. I really want the smart hiding feature that hides the launcher if it is in the way of the active window, and otherwise shows it. Currently, I have to tap the Windows-button every time I want to launch an application and it is really annoying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the [Dash To Dock extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/). I didn't turn it on, and I'm still using the dash (not a dock), but just installing the plugin fixed my problem. I have no idea why.